# Specifying layout in namespaced controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a new version of one of my controllers,

Original Controller:-

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
layout 'filename', only: [:method_name]
 ...
 def method_name
   #...some logic...
   respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json {
     render json: {}, root: false
   }
   end
 end
...
end
```

New Controller:-

```
class V1::ExampleController < ApplicationController
layout 'filename', only: [:method_name]
...
 def method_name
   #...some logic...
   respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json {
     render json: {}, root: false
   }
   end
 end
...
end
```

I keep getting error:-

```
Missing template v1/example/filename, application/filename with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :haml, :jbuilder]}
```

One of the solution is to create a folder structure v1/example and put my layout file there too. But I do not want to create duplicate copies of this file.

Another is to use a parent controller class of both new and old example_controller and specify layout there(and have a folder structure according to the name of the parent class). But this will be an overkill and also I plan on deleting old controller once all my clients migrate to new versions.

I also tried specifying like this:-

```
class V1::ExampleController < ApplicationController
layout 'example/filename', only: [:method_name]
...
end
```

but this also doesn't work.

How to tell my new controller to render layout from the old folder structure.

Comment: Try `append_view_path('/example')`

Comment: why did you add `ruby-on-rails-3` and `ruby-on-rails-4` tags? what is the version of rails?

Comment: @ArtemBiserov.... rails 3 tag removed. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
format.html {
  render template: 'path/to/template'
}
```

> **Rendering a template**
>
> Template rendering works just like action rendering except that it
>   takes a path relative to the template root. The current layout is
>   automatically applied.

```
# Renders the template located in [TEMPLATE_ROOT]/weblog/show.r(html|xml) (in Rails, app/views/weblog/show.erb)
render :template => "weblog/show"`
```

See [reference for #render](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render)